# Generate XML in proper syntax from SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, xml

How to write a SQL statement to generate XML like this

```
<ROOT>
  <Production.Product> 
     <ProductID>1 </ProductID>
     <Name>Adjustable Race</Name>
     ........
  </Production.Product>
</ROOT>
```

Currently I am getting this with

```
SELECT * FROM Production.Product
    FOR XML auto
```

Result is:

```
<ROOT>
   <Production.Product ProductID="1" Name="Adjustable Race" 
       ProductNumber="AR-5381" MakeFlag="0" FinishedGoodsFlag="0" 
       SafetyStockLevel="1000" ReorderPoint="750" StandardCost="0.0000" 
       ListPrice="0.0000" DaysToManufacture="0" SellStartDate="1998-06-01T00:00:00" 
       rowguid="694215B7-08F7-4C0D-ACB1-D734BA44C0C8" 
       ModifiedDate="2004-03-11T10:01:36.827" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One simple way would be to use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Production.Product
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
```

Then, your data should be stored in XML elements inside the `<Production.Product>` node.

If you need even more control, then you should look at the `FOR XML PATH` syntax - check out this MSDN article on [What's new in FOR XML in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) which explains the `FOR XML PATH` (among other new features).

Basically, with `FOR XML PATH`, you can control very easily how things are rendered - as elements or as attributes - something like:

```
SELECT 
    ProductID AS '@ProductID',  -- rendered as attribute on XML node
    Name, ProductNumber,        -- all rendered as elements inside XML node
    .....
FROM Production.Product
FOR XML PATH('NewProductNode')   -- define a new name for the XML node
```

This would give you something like:

```
<NewProductNode ProductID="1">
   <Name>Adjustabel Race</Name>
   <ProductNumber>AR-5381</ProductNumber>
   .....
</NewProductNode>
```